# In XSL, how can I print only the first line in for-each block?

Tags: xml, xslt

I made a list of books in XML. The following is the format of my XML file; there are some more `<book>` blocks, of course.

```
<data>
    <book>
        <title>Encyclopaedia Britannica</title>
        <category>encyclopedia</category>
        <language>English</language>
        <author>Encyclopaedia Britannica Editorial</author>
        <year>1768</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
</data>
```

And I want to print the title of the most expensive one. I tried as follows in the `.xsl` file:

```
<p style = "display: block;">
    The most expensive book is "
    <xsl:for-each select="data/book">
        <xsl:sort select="price" order="descending"/>
        <!-- <xsl:value-of select="title"/> -->
    </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="data/book/title"/>
    "
</p>
```

When the `<xsl:value-of>` block in `<xsl:for-each>`(which I set as comment) is executed it prints all the books sorted in descending order. Of course, `<xsl:value-of select="data/book/title"/>` makes the first book of the original table get printed.

So I want to print the most expensive one by stopping printing the other books but the first one when the table is sorted.

I know that there's no such thing like `break`, so I thought using `<xsl:if>` block to check if the row is the first or not. Is this idea possible? Or can I do this in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I thought using `<xsl:if>` block to check if the row is the first
>   or not.

Yes, this is the correct idea:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/book">
    <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that this selects only the first most expensive title in case of a tie.

---

> Or can I do this in another way?

That depends on which XSLT processor you use. In XSLT 2.0, you can use the `max()` function. And several XSLT 1.0 processors support the `math:max()` and `math:highest()` extension functions.

Comment: Hey man you got what I needed. I'm a noob in XSL programming and `prosition()` is a new one to me. Thanks!